# $scope in href - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an array like below;

```
$scope.cart = [];
```

This contains items like id, name etc.

How can I include the items in a `href` like below;

```
<a href="http://www.example.co.uk/search-menu/{{$scope.cart.restaurant_id}}/test">
```

This doesn't work.

I've also tried using `ng-repeat=item in cart`

FYI
When I `console.log($scope.cart)` I get the below;

```
[Object]
0: Object
cookie_id: "j0m3hdkf4c371nueajdi9gf4f3"
date: "0000-00-00"
day: ""
id: "92"
location: ""
restaurant_id: "1"
time: "00:00:00"
user_id: "63"
```

Comment: Expression does not need $scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Its Magic in Two way Data binding**

Use `ng-href` directive in angularjs

Remove `$scope` in the anchor tag.  You directly access the scope variable in the view part. In the controller part only we use `$scope` object is not need for html view.

```
<a ng-href="http://example.co.uk/search-menu{{cart[0].restaurant_id}}/test">
```

Comment: Again you mistake you ng-repeat with item but you used cart in anchor tag

Comment: use item instead of cart in the anchor tag. your code works beautiful

Comment: I'm no longer using `ng-repeat` based on this answer

Comment: it you not used ng-repeat then get index by zero

Comment: try <a ng-href="http://www.example.co.uk/search-menu/{{cart[0].restaurant_id}}/test">

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` should work actually. But you should try it with `ng-href`, like below...

In your HTML:

```
ng-repeat="item in cart" ng-href="yourUrl/{{item.id}}"
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.cart = [ cart1, cart2, ...];
```

If you get any errors, i would really help to see them here!

Answer (score 0):

First thing i would do is to remove the `$scope` in your controller and replace it with `this`

```
this.cart = [];
```

Then in your `View` you can use **Controller As** declaration then you will end up with dot notation (Which is the better way of doing it)

for example

```
    <div data-ng-controller="CartController as cart">
        <a ng-href="http://www.example.co.uk/search-menu/{{cart[0].restaurant_id}}/test">
    </div>
```